# Reading information from txt and placing that info to html (web page)

Tags: html

I have a question about html and txt files... I'm kind of new in html coding so I was wondering and searching for some help.

This is what I would need, making some web page for my company and wondering is there a way to read txt file in html and put that read data to my page...

For an example txt file would have timetable (who works - in my company - at certain time) and html file would display that information on a web page (ideal would be with a picture perhaps)

I hope you understood the question and thankfully would give me an answer and help.

Comment: you might have a look [here](http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson15.php)

Comment: btw - if you are a beginner maybe you should try to build your website with a simple cms like wordpress. It's really simple to create pages with the embedded texteditor. Better than to parse a textfile because if you parse a textfile you won't get formatted text like list, tables, linebreaks etc.. The editor in WP is a what you see is what you get editor.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is quite broad, whereas SO is better at answering specific programming questions. Read a beginner's tutorial for HTML perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at  [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

You'll need to do the file parsing with PHP of course.